# How to create google play menu in xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I'm new to Xamarin. How can i design a pop up menu that looks like google play menu in Xamarin ? I.e see the image below :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to go about making a fly-out menu, which is what I believe you are after. The very basic approach, is to add something similar to the following to your AXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<flyoutmenu.FlyOutContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include
        layout="@layout/MenuLayout" />
    <include
        layout="@layout/ContentLayout" />
</flyoutmenu.FlyOutContainer>
```

Source: http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/04/19/fly-out-menu-xamarin-android/

Another Source: http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2016/01/navigation-drawer-using-material-design.html

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. This is what i wanted. Especially the second link.